# Can I make .local implicit

Tags: hostname

On my LAN I have a host named **pleurotus**. I can ping **pleurotus.local** but not **pleurotus**-- the host isn't found.  Is there a way to make **.local** implicit, perhaps by putting some magical entry in the **hosts** file?

Answer (score 0):

Add `search local` to the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on modern systems returns `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`. Are you sure?

Comment: Apparently I need to use the resolvconf command with the -a option.  But resolvconf -a search local just sits there.

Comment: I've tried "resolvconf -a search.local" and "resolvconf -a search local" but neither command did anything.